# Testing for visibility of sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have excel file with following codes to select the sheets.
Also there are few sheets with "xlSheetVeryHidden" to hide.

My issue is hidden sheets appears with these codes, I don't want to show hidden sheet. How to do it?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim myList As String

Dim mySht

    For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count

    myList = myList & i & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name & " " & vbCr

    Next i

    mySht = InputBox("Select Sheet to go to." & vbCr & myList)

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(CInt(mySht)).Select

End Sub
```

Thanks,

Udara

Answer (score 2):

Sheets can have three properties for `.Visible` i.e `xlSheetHidden`, `xlSheetVeryHidden` and `xlSheetVisible`

So you can either check for `xlSheetHidden` and `xlSheetVeryHidden` or directly check for `xlSheetVisible`

For example

```
For Each oSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    '~~> Loop through only visible sheets
    If oSheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
        '
        '~~> Rest of your code
        '
    End If
Next oSheet
```

Answer (score 1):

You can determine a sheet is 'xlSheetVeryHidden' or not by checking Visible property.

Following code may show all sheets except sheets woth 'xlSheetVeryHidden' property.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim myList As String
    Dim i as integer
    Dim oSheet As Worksheet
    Dim mySht As String

    i = 1
    For Each oSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

        If oSheet.Visible <> xlSheetVeryHidden Then   'Only this line is changed from "Parash J"'s code.

            myList = myList & i & " - " & oSheet.Name & " " & vbCr
            i = i + 1

        End If

    Next oSheet

    mySht = InputBox("Select Sheet to go to." & vbCr & myList)

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(mySht).Select

End Sub
```

Code has been fixed. Code works well at Excel 2013.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, it is written with another few functions. Still I am trying to change it. Udara

Comment: mySht = InputBox("Select Sheet to go to." & vbCr & myList)

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have hide the sheet with `xlSheetVeryHidden` option, it will be available in VBA code. You will need to bypass that sheet in the `FOR LOOP`. You just need to include If Statement to check if `sheetname = "sheet1"` then don't include that sheet in the list.

Check this code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim myList As String
Dim i as integer
Dim mySht
     i = 1
     For Each oSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

        ''If oSheet.Name <> "Sheet1" Then '' to check for particular sheet.
          If oSheet.Visible <> xlSheetVeryHidden Then  '' For every sheet, set as xlsheetveryhidden 

            myList = myList & i & " - " & oSheet.Name & " " & vbCr
            i = i + 1

        End If

    Next oSheet

    mySht = InputBox("Select Sheet to go to." & vbCr & myList)

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(CInt(mySht)).Select

End Sub
```

Note: Where **Sheet1** is the very hidden sheet, you can name as you want.

Comment: Thanks Paresh, Still I am changing programme due other functions effect this.

Comment: Paresh, do you have any idea about this run time error?

Comment: In FUMU's code, he defined mySht as worksheet. Hence the error.

Comment: I have written as yours, ie. Dim mySht , still same error is there, please help me on this. Udara

Comment: It is running perfectly at my end. Please check at your end.

Comment: There are sheets like sheet1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 , sheet 3,4 & 5 applied xlSheetVeryHidden. It is running for sheet1 & 2. But sheet6,7,8 doesn't work.

Comment: Still error is there. It is actually complicated programme for me with so many other functions. thanks for your support. Udara

Comment: There are 10 sheets. First sheet called "Menu". Other sheets as Sheet 2 to Sheet 10. VeryHidden applied for Sheet 3,4 & 5. Now issue is this programme count VeryHidden sheets also. It doesn't appear. But Inbox No. doesn't work correctly.